# Swift Traling Closure Failure Without Meaningful Error

Tags: closures, swift

I am attempting to pass in a trailing closure parameter as follows (The code works without this function):

```
PNObservationCenter.defaultCenter().addClientConnectionStateObserver(self) { 
    (origin: String!, connected: Bool!, error: PNError!) in
    if (connected) {
        println("OBSERVER: Successful Connection!");
    } else if (!connected || error) {
        println("OBSERVER: \(error.localizedDescription), Connection Failed!");
    }
}
```

However, the build fails with this message:

Command /Applications/Xcode6-
Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254

Does anyone have insight into what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Edit: This code still crashes if implemented as a non-trailing closure or as a separate function passed as a parameter.

Comment: Does it work if your closure is not trailing? It looks like that's the compiler crashing btw, so even if your code is invalid, it's also a bug on apple's part

Comment: It still crashes if I define the function separately or implement this code as a non-trailing closure

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error after upgrading Xcode from beta 1 to beta 2. Apparently the closure definition has changed a little. Try using Void instead of (). So your code would be:

PNObservationCenter.defaultCenter().addClientConnectionStateObserver(self) {
    (origin: String!, connected: Bool!, error: PNError!) -> Void in
    if (connected) {
        println("OBSERVER: Successful Connection!");
    } else if (!connected || error) {
        println("OBSERVER: (error.localizedDescription), Connection Failed!");
    }
}

Comment: The code shouldn't even require a return statement. Unfortunately, he code you pasted here throws the same compile error, so does a closure with no return statement (Which according to the swift documentation is implicitly "-> ()").

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the closure args are wrong

```
 (origin: String!, connected: Bool!, error: PNError!) in
```

The connected argument should be of type Bool, not explicitly unwrapped optional Bool.

```
 (origin: String!, connected: Bool, error: PNError!) in
```

The compeller should have complained.  You should post to Radar.